# Least-Squares and Pseudoinverse of a Linear Transformation Proofs

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone please look through my work and see if the proofs are correct. Also, can you give me hints or anything to improve on. Thank you very much.

Consider a linear transformation L(⃗x) = A⃗x from ℝ<sup>m</sup> to ℝ<sup>n</sup> . The pseudoinverse L<sup>+</sup> of L is the transformation from ℝ<sup>n</sup> to ℝ<sup>m</sup> given by:

L<sup>+</sup> = (the minimal least-squares solution of the system L(⃗x) = ⃗y)

1. Show that the transformation L<sup>+</sup> is linear.
2. Suppose ker(L) = {0}, find the matrix for L<sup>+</sup>
3. Suppose rank(A) = n, find the matrix for L<sup>+</sup>
4. What is L<sup>+</sup>(L(⃗x)) for x in ℝ<sup>m</sup>
5. What is L(L<sup>+</sup>( ⃗y)) for y in ℝ<sup>n</sup>
6. Determine the image and the kernel of L<sup>+</sup> in terms of im(A<sup>T</sup>) and ker(A<sup>T</sup>)

MY WORK:

1. L<sup>+</sup>( ⃗y) = L<sup>+</sup>(k ⃗y + k ⃗z ) = kL<sup>+</sup>( ⃗y) + kL<sup>+</sup>( ⃗z)
2. ker(L) = {0} implies that ker(A) = ker(A<sup>T</sup>A) = {0}. This implies that A<sup>T</sup>A is invertible. The invertibility implies that there exists a solution ̂ ⃗x such that ̂ ⃗⃗x satisfies the least-squares equation.

(A<sup>T</sup>A ̂ ⃗x)<sup>-1</sup>A  = A<sup>T</sup> ⃗b

therefore, the matrix for L<sup>+</sup> is:

̂ ⃗⃗x = (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>T</sup> ⃗y

3. rank(A) = n implies that im(A) = ℝ<sup>n</sup>. (Now I don't know how to proceed). . .
4. Geometric Interpretation:

   ⃗x = ⃗x<sup>ll</sup> + ⃗x<sup>perp</sup> where  ⃗x<sup>ll</sup> is in ker(L) and  ⃗x<sup>perp</sup> is in ker(L) <sup>perp</sup>

L( ⃗x)  = L(x<sup>ll</sup> + ⃗x<sup>perp</sup>) = L(x<sup>ll</sup>) + L(x<sup>perp</sup>) = L(x<sup>perp</sup>)

this implies that  L( ⃗x) = L(x<sup>perp</sup>).  Now we apply L<sup>+</sup> onto L( ⃗x)

L<sup>+</sup>(L( ⃗x)) = L<sup>+</sup>(Lx<sup>perp</sup>) = x<sup>perp</sup>

This implies that L<sup>+</sup>L = proj<sub>(kerL)<sup>perp</sup></sub>  ⃗x

5. (I'm not sure what to do here).

6.(part 1)... ker(L<sup>+</sup>) implies that  ⃗y is in the ker(L<sup>+</sup>), so that implies that L<sup>+</sup> ⃗y = 0.

therefore, L<sup>+</sup> ⃗y = 0 implies that L(0) = ⃗y. which implies that ker(L<sup>+</sup>) = 0

A<sup>T</sup>A ⃗x* = A<sup>T</sup> ⃗y implies that A<sup>T</sup>A(0) = A<sup>T</sup> ⃗y = A<sup>T</sup> ⃗y = 0 which implies that ker(L<sup>+</sup>) = ker(A<sup>T</sup>)

(part b)...

im(L<sup>+</sup>) = L<sup>+</sup> ⃗y =  ⃗x implies that  ⃗x is in the ker(A<sup>T</sup>)